# matrix of basis vector of a linear map is column of the matrix of that linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I've gotten very confused about this statement in [Axler, *Linear Algebra Done Right* (2015)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKhJN.png):

Suppose $ T\in \mathcal{L}(V,W) $ and $ v_{1},\cdots,v_{n} \in V $ is a basis of $ V $ and $ w_{1},\cdots,w_{m} $ is a basis of $ W $. Let $ 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n $. Then the $ k^{th} $ column of $\mathcal{M}(T)$, denoted by $ \mathcal{M}(T)_{\cdot,k} $, equals $\mathcal{M}(v_{k})$. Ie:

$$ \mathcal{M}(T)_{\cdot,k} = \mathcal{M}(v_{k}) $$

I'm either not understanding what $ \mathcal{M}(v_{k}) $ means or I have totally misunderstood this chapter on matrices. Surely the columns of $\mathcal{M}(T)$ will vary with how $T$ is defined and not be defined wholly by the basis of the domain of T? Moreover, I was under the impression that the columns of the matrix of a linear map were *a* basis for the range of that linear map.

I think the misunderstanding is in what $\mathcal{M}(v_{k})$ means.

Consider the simple example of $ T:V \rightarrow W$ where $ V,W \in \mathbb{R}^{2} $. The basis of $V$ and $W$ is the standard basis $(1,0), (0,1)$.  $T$ is defined by: $T(x,y)=(x+y,2x+y)$. Then:

$$\mathcal{M}(T) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

and,

$$ \mathcal{M}(T)_{\cdot,1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \neq \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \mathcal{M}(v_{1}) $$

However, $\mathcal{M}(Tv_{1}) = \mathcal{M}((1(1)+(1)(0), 2(1)+1(0))) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ which is equal to the first column of $\mathcal{M}(T)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it is a typo in the book. Let me rewrite the definition 3.62 using a more precisely notation:

> **Definition.** Suppose $v \in V$ and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is basis for $V$. Then we define
> $$\mathcal M(v,(v_1,\dots,v_n)) = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_n \end{pmatrix}$$
> where $c_1,\dots,c_n$ are scalars such that $v = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_nv_n$.

Then, using that the $k$-th column of a matrix $A$ is denoted in the book by $A_{\cdot,k}$, the result 3.64 says the following:

> **Theorem.** Let $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$, $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be a basis for $V$ and $w_1,\dots,w_m$ be a basis for $W$. Then for each $1 \leq k \leq n$,
> $$\mathcal M(T,(v_1,\dots,v_n),(w_1,\dots,w_m))_{\cdot,k} = \mathcal M(Tv_k,(w_1,\dots,w_m)).$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. Just checked the errata to the third edition and there it is.